# How do I get .NET to report the current node level using SiteMapDataSource?

Tags: asp.net

I am using SiteMapDataSource to drive the navigation of my site using a Menu control. I would like to create some sub-navigation that is context aware, i.e. showing certain child nodes within the Web.sitemap.

I know that the requested page's context gets reported to the control, but how can I access this numerical positioning to use in programming logic?

In pseudo code, I would like to say, when the page is found on **level X** of the sitemap, do Y.

Comment: Have you tried something like `SiteMapNode currNode = System.Web.SiteMap.CurrentNode`?

Comment: you *should* be able to do that and get useful information about the current node.

Comment: System.Web.SiteMap.CurrentNode will report the title of the current node. It doesn't show any context, i.e. at what node level the title is located.

Comment: It does -- you can get the `ParentNode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a better way to do this. One way to get the level of the node:

```
SiteMapNode c = System.Web.SiteMap.CurrentNode;
int lvl = 0;
while (c.ParentNode != null)
{
    c = c.ParentNode;
    lvl++;
}
```